# Need to convert rtept to trkpt, any XSL available before I write one?

Tags: gpx

I don't mind writing [XSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Stylesheet_Language) but if one has already been written I should reuse it.

rtept = route point in the [GPX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_eXchange_Format) format
trkpt = track point in the GPX format

Converting latitude and longitude points from the first to the second, ignoring irrelevant elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless someone proves me wrong, there is no such XSL application available.

I would have loved to contribute one, but incidentally the whole point of the conversion disappeared when I discovered that [GMapToGPX](http://www.elsewhere.org/journal/gmaptogpx/) can generate files in the trkpt format directly.